# Where is VAT collected if a private Non-EU person sends an invoice to a EU company?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, vat

my online research did not yield any meaningful results for my situation, so i hope to find someone who has expert knowledge or had a similar situation:

I live in Taiwan now using a so called 'Gold Card', which is an alien resident cerificate that allows me to stay here for three years and conduct business. Before that, I was living in Germany as a german citizen, but deregistered from Germany so I do not have to pay income taxes in Germany anymore (-> no tax residency in Germany now). Now i want to invoice a german company for IT services that I, as a private person, provide from my new home in Taiwan.

I am unsure if i have to add german VAT, which would be 19%, on the invoice that I present to them? I doubt that i have to do that but maybe i am missing something?

Steve